# How/where does rustup export the PATH variable?

Tags: rustup

What is the mechanism that rustup uses to set the `PATH` variable? I couldn't find any entry in my `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `PATH` variable is exported in `.profile` in the user home directory:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: depends on the shell used to run rustup, [it has specific cases for some shells, currently bash and zsh](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/blob/4cbc7855167c11108c1036391d58b1d794d700fb/src/cli/self_update/shell.rs#L106).

Answer (score 0):

The following command works on Mac:

`source $HOME/.cargo/env`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rustup installed by package manager(pacman) to manage rust environment in Arch Linux, at first I don't know how does it set `PATH`. Then I run `pacman -Ql rustup` to list all files the package has installed and found there's a file `/etc/profile.d/rustup.sh` and its content:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/rustup/bin
```

So it's a global profile file and all shells will source it.
I don't know which distro you are using but it must be in similar condition.